# Google Analytics simple client

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to integrate GA into a QT5 / QML project. For this I created a dummy GA web page project to test connectivity. First step is to test the setup with a simple web page (code below).
I had to specify a URL for the GA project. The page, however, is on my desktop, not online. I see no traffic in the real time GA view. Not sure why. Is it that my page is not on `www.my-domain.com` but literally on my desktop?

**SETUP**
On the GA settings page, this is my setup

```
Basic Settings

Tracking Id
UA-1234567890-1
Property Name

Default URL
http://www.my-domain.com
```

**LOCAL TEST PAGE CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-1234567890-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'TEST');
    console.log(ga.q);
  </script>


</head>
<body>

<button onclick="ga('send', 'BUTTON PUSH')">
    PUSH ME
</button>



</body>
</html>
```

I have used GA before and do not remember the integration was this bumpy. Right now, I am also confused by the difference of GA view and Firebase view on the live report. However, I first need to establish proper tracking.

Comment: can you please check Analytics Realtime reports for any data?

Comment: Yes, no realtime data comes up.